# animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path='pose.bones["Leg"].rotation_euler', index = 2)

Tags: bones, fcurves

```
obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path='pose.bones["Leg"].rotation_euler', index = 2)
```

data_path is treat as string rather than rotation_euler.
[image]

*I want to edit fcurve returned directly, but bone.keyframe_insert does not return it*

Solved.
The bone name is incorrect, and I found that the quote around bone name must be double-quote

Comment: can you demonstrate via UI what you are trying to do? so we can analyze how to covert it to python.

Comment: The code is right. Maybe you are wrong with the naming, double-check bone name.

Comment: @Crantisz You're right, the problem is wrong bone name. Thank you very much!